# Using ksoap2 to call Soap web services. My application crashes

Tags: android, web-services, soap, wsdl

I need to call soap web service in my project. I have followed a tutorial on YouTube to achieve this task using ksoup2. The application they show in the tutorial run well. But the application crashes (says "Unfortunately, My Test has stopped") as soon as a white screen begins to appear on the emulator. [Here](http://pastebin.com/tSeAyw0C) is the **LogCat**.

1. Can you please see the code and logcat and tell me what is wrong
   with it, and how do I fix it.
2. I have seen some tutorials in which they give the path of the WSDL in URL, which they give the path to where the web service is (like in this one) in others. What is the difference between the two.

CODE:-

```
package com.falafel.myTest;
//ANDROID CLIENT OF SOAP WEB SERVICES. SAMPLE (YOUTUBE) CLIENT.
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FirstScreen extends Activity {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION= "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit"; //soapAction will point to where the namespace is, slash, the name of the method
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME= "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static final String URL= "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";//This URL is very important. Make sure it is pointing to asmx, and not to wsdl, that is a complete URL to where the web service itself is; This is not a WSDL file.

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        //Soap Portion of this client program starts here. This is 1/3rd of the major functionality of this program, since there are three major portions.
        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);//If we CelsiusToFahrenheit dint take any parameters, I would be done with my soap request by this line. But it does take a string parameter (as we say in the wsdl), so we need to package the required parameters into the Request. That is, next line!
        Request.addAttribute("Celsius", "32"); //Celcius is the name of the parameter required by the function. 32 --> we are giving a hardcoded value here for simplicity. | We have to add this line for each required parameter.


        //Here starts the 2nd out of 3 major portions of this program. This portion is the SoapSerializationEnvelope, which is an important piece of what needs to happen in ksoap to call web services inside of android.
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); //An important thing in creating this object is specifying which version of the soap specification we want to use. This is version 1.1
                                                                                                    //soapEnvelope is an in and out object, which means that it has 2 types of information clusters, named bodyIn which contains information we send to web service while making the call (i.e. the xml going out), and named bodyOut which brings back, from the web service, the response of the call to the web service (that is the xml coming in).
        soapEnvelope.dotNet= true; //Remember the asmx in the URL, that is this service is based in ASP.Net, and not PHP or something, so you have to specify that. If you forget to specify that, you'll get some errors complaining that some of your objects are NULL. And the tricky part is that sometimes it will work, so yeah! If you are sure that yours is a dotNet based web service, always be safe by setting it to true, and if it is not dotNet based, you'll have to set it to nottrue
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request); //Pass the packaged Request to SoapEnvelope itself. SetOutputSoapObject() assigns the object to the envelope as the outbound message for the soap call.


        //3rd of the 3 major parts of this program:- Transport (HTTP transport itself)
        HttpTransportSE hts= new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try{   //try-catch block to actually make the call
            hts.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope); //SOAP_ACTION contains where the web service is, appended with the function to be invoked. While all the information which needs to be sent to the web service is present (like Request) in the bodyIn portion of the soapEnvelope. After the call is successful (i.e. after the execution of this line, the bodyOut portion of this envelope will contain the response of the webservice.
            SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            tv.setText("Status : " + resultString);
        }   
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

STRING RESOURSE: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">My Test</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

</resources>
```

MANIFEST FILE:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.falafel.myTest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.falafel.myTest.FirstScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LAYOUT:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".FirstScreen" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

1. Right Click the Project and Select **Properties**
2. Click on the "Java Build Path" from the left panel.
3. On the Right Side CHECK **ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4**.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use this :-
>
> ```
> 1.-Download the Ksoap jar file if you are not and paste in libs folder than right click of that and add build path 
> 2.-and import all that class 
> 3.-and give the network state change permission
> ```